# Does the current path matter for some git operations?

Tags: git, path, commit, relative-path, patch

Say, I have my git repo (the `.git` folder) located in `~/my_project/`. Assume also that my project's folder is assembled like that:

```
my_project
      |
      |____src
            |
            |__com
            |
            |__org
```

Last of all, assume that I'd like to stage the `com` folder for commit. I may do it in at least two ways:

- `albus@hogwarts:~/my_project$ git add src/com`
- `albus@hogwarts:~/my_project/src$ git add com`

Would there be any difference between the two invocations? What about `git format-patch` or `git am`? Do they depend on the current path?

People may laught at my question, but truth is, a colleague of mine said that they had trouble applying some patches, i.e. they had to apply them from different directories in the project path. They also recommended that I should do all git commands from the upmost project folder (i.e. `my_project` in this example). I never though there might be truth in this, but I'm not an expert where git comes into the picture and therefore I'm asking it here.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, I just checked `format-patch` (you can do that to, thanks to git being decentralized, you can create repo anytime anywhere). It gives the same output no matter what directory you are in, files are identical.

Comment: Yep, you're right, I *could* try it myself, but expert's knowledge is always worth hearing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git format-patch` creates the same patch wherever you ran the command. Only thing that changes is *where* the patch file is generated.

But different commands behave differently, which also depends on flags applied to them.

For example, `git diff` has the `--relative` flag:

> --relative[=`<path>`]
>
> When run from a subdirectory of the project, it can be told to exclude changes outside the directory and show pathnames relative to
>   it with this option. When you are not in a subdirectory (e.g. in a
>   bare repository), you can name which subdirectory to make the output
>   relative to by giving a  as an argument.